# Instantiate an instance of a class from a string in lua

Tags: class, lua, game-development, love2d

I have a function to spawn Enemies that will choose an entity name at random from a list.  These names are strings, such as 'spider', 'mole', 'bee', etc.  I want to then take that string and use it create an instance of the entity.  Each Entity has its own script and behavior.

```
local entity = ENTITIES[math.random(1, #ENTITIES)]
        
     new_entity = entity({
            x = 0, 
            y = 0
     })
```

Where entity could be "mole", instead of

```
if entity == 'mole' then Mole({
            x = 0,
            y = 0
        })
elseif entity == 'spider' then Spider({
```

I am sure that this question has been answered, but I don't quite know how to look it up.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just store the entity constructor in `ENTITIES` and pair it with an array that has all the keys that you can use random to get? `local entity = ENTITIES[ENTITIES_KEYS[math.random(1, #ENTITIES_KEYS)]]`

Comment: FYI, `Mole({})` (if Mole is defined in global namespace) is the synonym for `_G["Mole"]({})`. Afaik in recent versions of Lua they introduced `_ENV["Mole"]({})` to be exact synonym of `Mole({})` always (with no ifs).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and also probably the nicest is to simply use a table of constructors:

```
local ENTITY_CONSTRUCTORS  = {
spider=Spider,
mole=Mole,
bat=Bat,
...
}
```

And then:

```
local entity = ENTITIES[math.random(#ENTITIES)]
local object = ENTITY_CONSTRUCTORS[entity]{ x=0, y=0 }
```

You may even simplify further by storing constructors directly in ENTITIES table:

```
ENTITIES = { Spider, Mole, Bat }
local object = ENTITIES[math.random(#ENTITIES)]{ x=0, y=0 }
```